# The name "StatusToStringConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Editor"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums

I am trying to bind data to a textbox in WPF. But it fails. I do bind Enum to a Radio Button in the same application, this works fine; but when I try to bind Enum to a Textbox it fails. What am I doing wrong?

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="formatTextStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Palatino Linotype"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value ="14"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="CommandTarget" Value="{Binding ElementName=mainRTB}"></Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="formatImageStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="CommandTarget" Value="{Binding ElementName=mainRTB}"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <local:EnumToBooleanConverter x:Key="EnumToBooleanConverter" />
    <local:StatusToStringConverter x:Key="StatusToStringConverter" />
</Grid.Resources>

<RadioButton IsEnabled="False" Click="DisplayFormatChanged" Name="BinaryButton" Content="_Binary" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DisplayFormat, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:displayFormat.Binary}}" />
<RadioButton IsEnabled="False" Click="DisplayFormatChanged" Name="HexButton" Content="_Hex" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DisplayFormat, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:displayFormat.Hex}}" />

<TextBlock Name="Status"  IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Path=Status, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource StatusToStringConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:Status.NotStarted}}"/>
```

And code behind looks like this:

```
namespace Editor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    { //rest of my code goes in here}

    [ValueConversion(typeof(displayFormat), typeof(Boolean))]
    public class EnumToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)

        {
            return value.Equals(parameter);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value.Equals(true) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
        }
    }

    [ValueConversion(typeof(Status), typeof(String))]
    public class StatusToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), value.ToString(), true);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please add the rest of your xaml so that we can see where you are attempting to use the converter.  Also, I don't think you need a converter that simply calls the ToString() method - that should be done automatically in WPF when the bound type is not a string.

Comment: @Andrew: I have added rest of the code as per you request. I tried restarting Visual Studios, but it does not work. No I need to a converter when I bind Enum to Textbox.

Comment: How does it fail? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: It fails during compiling, "The name “StatusToStringConverter” does not exist in the namespace “clr-namespace:Editor”", even though I have ot defined.

Comment: It works now; Switching solution configuration from Debug to Release - and switch back configuration from Release to Debug

Comment: Doing a clean might have worked as well. Always clean if things get weird.

Comment: @Steve: Cleaning the solution and rebuilding did not help.

Comment: Again, please add the rest of your XAML - you have only included the grid's resource section.

Comment: Also, you're using the namespace PatternEditor to define your converters, not Editor, as the exception would suggest

Comment: And, I also assure you that you absolutely do not need an EnumToString converter

Comment: @Andrew: I added the code, where I am using these controls.

Comment: the problem is probably where you define the local xml namespace

Comment: @Andrew: I got the problem resolved. Please see my previous comments.

Comment: @savi Wow I just encountered the same problem, and switching from Debug to Release and back really fixed it! Thanks!